# Issues with Monte Carlo Simulation in R

Tags: r, montecarlo

This is my code, but I am facing some issues. This line:   results <- MonteCarlo(model, n = 10000),  gives me the following error:

```
Error in MonteCarlo(model, n = 10000) : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

This is the whole code. Can anyone see where I have made a mistake?

```
install.packages("MonteCarlo")
library(MonteCarlo)


year1.price <- 1800 
year2.price <- c(-250, 200, 500) 
year3.price <- c(-250, 200, 500) 
year4.price <- c(-250, 200, 500) 
year5.price <- c(-250, 200, 500) 

output.distribution <- c(100, 1000, 1800) 
annual.change <- c(-0.15, 0.3, 0.7) 
fixed.costs <- c(500000, 750000, 1000000) 
legal.costs <- c(500000, 750000, 1000000) 

 
model <- function() { 
  year1.revenue <- year1.price * output.distribution[2] 
  year2.revenue <- year2.price[sample(1:3, 1)] * (output.distribution[2] + output.distribution[2] * annual.change[sample(1:3, 1)]) 
  year3.revenue <- year3.price[sample(1:3, 1)] * (output.distribution[2] + output.distribution[2] * annual.change[sample(1:3, 1)]) 
  year4.revenue <- year4.price[sample(1:3, 1)] * (output.distribution[2] + output.distribution[2] * annual.change[sample(1:3, 1)]) 
  year5.revenue <- year5.price[sample(1:3, 1)] * (output.distribution[2] + output.distribution[2] * annual.change[sample(1:3, 1)]) 
  
  total.revenue <- year1.revenue + year2.revenue + year3.revenue + year4.revenue + year5.revenue 
  total.costs <- fixed.costs[2] + legal.costs[sample(1:3, 1)] 
  net.revenue <- total.revenue - total.costs 
  
  return(net.revenue) 
} 

results <- MonteCarlo(model, n = 10000)


summary(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are getting is because `MonteCarlo` does not have an argument called `n`. The argument you are looking for is called `nrep`. However, fixing this will give you another error saying that your list of parameters is missing. The reason for this is simply that you are using the wrong function here.

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get 10000 repetitions of the function `model`. However, `MonteCarlo` is designed to be used in more complex situations where you want replicates of a function that accepts multiple parameters which may vary over the replicates. Your function does not take any parameters, so `MonteCarlo` throws an error, and in any case you can get the result you are looking for simply by using the base R function `replicate`, which will do just what you are looking for

```r
results <- replicate(10000, model())
```

So for example:

```r
length(results)
#> [1] 10000

mean(results)
#> [1] 1075661

hist(results)
```

[image]